# Tag synonym request: [gameboy] → [game-boy]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Game Boy is two words, so I would like to request that [gameboy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy) be renamed/made a synonym of [game-boy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy).

Comment: Even Nintendo gets confused sometimes, but it does appear that you're right about the official name. +1

Comment: I'd do this myself, but I can't create [tag:game-boy] because [tag:gameboy] exists!

Comment: Could someone flag this [tag:status-completed]? Someone took care of it.

Comment: Thanks @JuanManuel.

Answer (score 4):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)